# How can I prove $AX=BX$ for every $n\times1$ column matrix $X \implies A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices $n\times n$.

Suppose $AX=BX$ for every $n\times 1$ column matrix $X$.

How can I prove this implies $A=B$?

Comment: Consider $X=e_1$, i.e. the first entry is $1$ and all other entries are $0$.  What does this tell you about $A,B$?

Comment: Just a note, your statement is not commutative, meaning if $XA=XB$ then we cannot arbitrarily say $A=B$

Comment: @imranfat interesting, do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, examine $A= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -3 \\ -4 & 6 \end{pmatrix} $, $ B=\begin{pmatrix} 8 & 4 \\ 5 & 5 \end{pmatrix} $  and $C= \begin{pmatrix} 5 & -2 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $ Now verify that $AB=AC$ but $B$ is not $C$

Comment: @imranfat I thought you have said for every $X$

Comment: @user42912, not for every $X$, but my point was, that the "cancelation property" from algebra does not carry over to matrix algebra. That is why I edited the title to a specific $n$by$1$ dimension for $X$.. The sentence "How can I prove this implies $A=B$" needs to be taken with caution....

Comment: @imranfat yes, thank you for your comments.

Comment: Just some terminology, I think you should call $X$ a vector, by convention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $e_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector. Then for all $1\leq i \leq n$,

$$Ae_i = Be_i.$$

But $Ae_i$ and $Be_i$ are just the $i^{th}$ columns of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Comment: One thing that bothers me is that merely the null spaces could be equal/x could be zero. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419292/in-any-vector-space-ax-bx-implies-a-b However, I guess we have a stronger antecedent here (we explicitly say this is true for *all* elts) and hence why we are able to easily prove it

Answer (score 4):

Consider the column vectors $e_i$ which are all $0$s except for the $i$th component. Then $Ae_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$, which is the same as the $i$th column of $B$, $Be_i$. Thus, all the columns in $A$ equal the corresponding columns in $B$.